# Test Laravel API on localhost cannot get response

Tags: php, laravel, curl, localhost

So have this laravel get product api that works if i called it from the browser as you can see from this image

[image]

here is the curl code chunk that tried to get this json response

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/products';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($data,true);
echo $result;
```

but i cannot get anything in result, nothing to echo. I have one mockable api in https://demo0546443.mockable.io/products/getAllProducts that produce nearly the same json as my localhost api and it return response as it should have. please help

**SOLUTION**
So after countless hours researching about this, it seems laravel needs to be accessed on static ip, not on localhost.

Comment: Where are you running this test code from? Remember that only your pc has access to localhost.

Comment: `var_dump($data);`

Comment: i test the code from the same computer as i run my laravel api server

Comment: What happens if you var_dump($result); ?  Laravel also offers dd($result); which essentially var_dump() enhanced formatting.

Comment: Looks like you didn't pass any authentication to your api.  Where did you register your api routes?

Comment: I didnt put any authentication to my getProducts, as u can see via web browser the api responded. sorry i am new to laravel

Comment: What if you add the port in the options? `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8000);`

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I too having the same issue in Laravel. But after adding curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3); It's then working, even on localhost

Answer (score 0):

It’s recommended to use a library like [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) though to make HTTP requests instead though.its very eazy to implement and work with

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `echo $result` try `return response()->json($data)`.

`echo $result`  return Header `application/html` while `json()` return `application/json` hope this helps.